# how to save the textbox value when trigger any selected manual event in page zk framework

Tags: java, zk

Can i use any event name here to bind the value or sever side calling any method then it will be bind. Please find below code provided by ZK.

```
<intbox value="@load(vm.selected.quantity) @save(vm.selected.quantity,before='saveOrder') "/>
```

> dirty checking server side operation

here when clicking saveorder button it's working properly. but i need when any method call by inside java code then it should be bind.

> tab change

another requirement is when i am changing tab before it should be bind the value.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no way to bind the saving process automatically, therefore you can put in your `before` condition multiple commands:

```
@save(vm.selected.quantity,before={'saveOrder', 'otherCommand', 'anotherOne'})
```

For the tab changing (if you are refering to the ZK component), you can bind the `onSelect` event of the tabbox to a command and add it to the `before` condition

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use @bind in value

`<intbox value="@bind(vm.selected.quantity)"/>`.

Then the value will be automaticly saved whenever intbox was changed.
Or  if you need validation :

`<intbox value="@bind(vm.selected.quantity) @validator(vm.validator)" />`

validator is an instance of a class that implements `org.zkoss.bind.Validator`, `org.zkoss.bind.AbstractValidator` for example.

Here is ZK wiki about validation:
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Validator